# get element index of an object

Tags: javascript, json

i need to get the index of an element in this object (returned as `JSON.parse(data)`), i tried with `findIndex`
`datosReserva`, `datosReserva.Reservas` and nothing... it says `findIndex` is not a function.

```
function checkReserva(){
 
  var options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'uri': urlAPI,
    'headers': {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    
    }
  };
request(options, function (error, response) {
  let reserva;
  if (error){ 
    throw new Error(error);
  }else {
   // console.log(response.body);
    reserva = response.body;
    //console.log(reserva)

  }
return checkIndex(reserva, "2929 25-06-2020 10:00");
//"2929 25-06-2020 10:00" for testing
});

}
```

```
function checkIndex(datosReserva, reserva) {
    const elemento = (element) => element.reserva == reserva;
    console.log(datosReserva.findIndex(elemento))
}
```

```
{
  "Reservas": [
    {
      "reserva": "2929 22-06-2020 11:20",
      "id": "1",
      "status": "on"
    },
    {
      "reserva": "2929 25-06-2020 10:00",
      "id": "5",
      "status": "on"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: where's the code that calls the `checkIndex` function?

Comment: Also, `checkIndex` function **returns nothing**...

Comment: Working fine for me.

Comment: I just edited your question without changing your logic, and even that is giving correct result.

Comment: just added the function that calls checkIndex

Comment: try indexOf function

Comment: returns nothing because im testing with console, it will return the index -1 or n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i found the solution. I needed to parse the response to object. Thank you everyone!!

```
function checkIndex(datosReserva, stringReserva){
  var reservas = JSON.parse(datosReserva)
  const elemento= (element) => element.reserva == stringReserva;
var index = reservas.Reservas.findIndex(elemento);
  console.log(reservas.Reservas.findIndex(elemento));
 //return index;
}
```

Comment: the response of checkReserva was a String... i did convert the response.body to object before tho but didn't work... a simply pc restart always works haha.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Reservas = Json.parse(response.body).Reservas;
return checkIndex(Reservas , "2929 25-06-2020 10:00");
function checkIndex(Reservas, reserva) {
    let index = -1;
    Reservas.forEach((element, idx)=>{
         if(element.reserva == reserva) {
            index = idx;
         }
    });
    return index;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @Francisco Prieto 
you should parse your response first and then invoke the function 
var Reservas = JSON.parse(datosReserva).Reservas;
return checkIndex(Reservas , "2929 25-06-2020 10:00")

Comment: yes, that fixed it, i tried that before and didn't work don't know why hahah